# Query Database by ID for page title and content

Tags: php, mysql, sql, content-management-system

This one is very simple, but I've gone in so many circles today I'm completely lost!

I'm trying to grab the correct page title and page content, based upon a variable I set at the top of the page. ie:

```
<?php 
$pageIDn = 2;
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/includes/functions.php');
content($pageIDn); // the function that queries the DB
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/includes/header.php'); ?>
```

Within functions then I have this function/query:

```
function content($pageID){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = 1");
    $title = $query['title'];
    $content = $query['content'];
}
```

And then in the relevant locations in the file I'm trying to echo the variables ie:

```
<h2><?php echo $content; ?></h2>
```

I know I've made a very stupid mistake here somewhere... just not sure where.

Comment: Is there an error on the page?

Comment: Two mistakes: Not enabling error_reporting, and not looking at the manual examples for [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query)  right away. (Also, still using mysql_query is a mistake in itself. But it's entirely your decision to use the more cumbersome api.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three **big** errors:

1. You forgot to put your `$pageID` in your query:

   ```
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = {$pageID}");
   ```
2. ...to fetch your results:

   ```
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
   $title = $row['title'];
   $content = $row['content'];
   ```
3. ...and return and capture your output:

   ```
   return array($title, $content);

   list($title, $content) = content($pageIDn);
   ```

Stack Overflow:

```
$pageIDn = 2;
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/includes/functions.php');
list($title, $content) = content($pageIDn); // the function that queries the DB
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/includes/header.php'); ?>

function content($pageID){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = {$pageID}");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $title = $row['title'];
    $content = $row['content'];
    return array($title, $content);
}
```

Also, [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: also you have to set the $content variable as a global variable to use it outside the function too.

Comment: Actually I don't because it is in the array that is returned by ` content()`

Comment: Thank you very much - it's all so simple when the glaring mistakes are pointed out! Very appreciated.

Comment: Also regarding the depreciated mysql_*, I wasn't even aware! I've basically hashed together a basic CMS from this tutorial: http://www.melvinwalls.com/2011/01/creating-a-basic-cms-with-php-and-mysql-part-1/ but using it in quite a different way.

Answer (score 1):

You first mistake is forget about MYSQL_***. Use PDO
Second, you said you wanted to grab $pageIDn = 2, but you did not use at all.

```
function content($pageID){
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = ".$pageIDn." ");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$title = $query['title'];
$content = $query['content'];
 }
```